# Repeating period in non binary numeral systems

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across this question -> [Repeating period in binary conversion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807879/repeating-period-in-binary-conversion/4022759#4022759). I want to know if there is a way to calculate repeating period in numeral systems with base other than 2.

For example:

Number $0.1_{10}$ is $0.01212121212121..._4$ so there are **2** repeating ciphers .

Number $0.1_{10}$ is $0.02222222222222222222...._5$ so there is only **1** repeating cipher .

Also I noticed that the repeating periods are repeating :

number 0.1

base 2 repeating period : **4**

base 3 repeating period : **4**

base 4 repeating period : **2**

base 5 repeating period : **1**

base 6 repeating period : **1**

base 7 repeating period : **4**

base 8 repeating period : **4**

base 9 repeating period : **2**

base 10 repeating period : **1**

base 11 repeating period : **1**

So if there is way to calculate even these repeatings ? Thanks.

Comment: This is an interesting (& important) topic! It would be hard to fully explain what's going on and make it fit into a Stack Exchange answer. ;) While waiting for an answer, I suggest you do some more exploring. Look at the periods of the reciprocals of small prime numbers in various bases, eg 1/7, 1/11, 1/23, 1/43.

Answer (score 1):

As you will have seen from the other post, if the base $b$ is coprime to $10$ then the period $p$ for the number $0.1_{10}$ will be the least power of $b$ such that $b^p\equiv 1\pmod {10}.$ Note that
$$3^4\equiv 1\pmod {10}$$
$$7^4\equiv 1\pmod {10}$$
$$9^2\equiv 1\pmod {10}$$
$$11^1\equiv 1\pmod {10}$$
This will give us a pattern which repeats every $10$ bases since $13\equiv 3\pmod {10}$, $15\equiv 5\pmod {10}$ and so on.

If the base $b$ is even but coprime to $5$ then the period $p$ will be the least power of $b$ such that $b^p\equiv 1\pmod {5}.$ Note that
$$2^4\equiv 1\pmod {5}$$
$$4^2\equiv 1\pmod {5}$$
$$6^1\equiv 1\pmod {5}$$
$$8^4\equiv 1\pmod {5}$$
Again this will give us a pattern which repeats every $10$ bases.

If the base $b$ is odd but but a multiple $5$ then the period $p=1$ since $b^p\equiv 1\pmod {2}.$ The period is also $1$ if $b$ is a multiple of $10$.

This gives you the pattern you have noticed with overall period  being $5$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Glad to be of help.